# Fatal error when trying to check out another branch using git

Tags: git

I was trying to take a look at another branch by a developer and when I did this command:

```
git checkout -b master origin/new_branch_name
```

I got this error message:

```
fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'master' at the same time. Did you intend to checkout 'origin/new_branch_name' which can not be resolved as commit?
```

Dd I miss some step? Would anyone know what I did wrong? Was I supposed to create the repository locally first?

Comment: I suspect either that `master` already exists (it does in most repos), and so creating a new branch named `master` fails, or `origin/new_branch_name` does not exist...

Comment: @twalberg ah yes, the master does exist for me. I wasn't trying to create a new master branch. I was trying to download the new branch called new_branch_name ....did I mess up the syntax of the command?

Comment: The syntax is `git checkout -b what_the_new_local_branch_should_be_called where_the_new_local_branch_should_start_from`... So, e.g. `git checkout -b new_branch_name origin/new_branch_name` to reduce future confusion from mis-matched local/remote branch names...

Comment: @twalberg thank you. I just tried: git checkout -b vidals-mods  origin/vidals-mods and I got this error: 
fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'vidals-mods' at the same time.
Did you intend to checkout 'origin/vidals-mods' which can not be resolved as commit?

Comment: The vidals-mods branch is the new one that I don't currently have locally.

Comment: Ok, does `git branch -r` show that `origin/vidals-mods` is a valid branch (alternatively, does `git rev-parse origin/vidals-mods` give back a hash value?)? If not, then you probably need to `git fetch origin` first...

Comment: @twalberg git branch -r does not show that branch. And the other command you suggested (git rev-parse origin/vidals-mods) gives this error: fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/vidals-mods': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.

Comment: What will git fetch origin do?

Comment: `git fetch origin` will make sure that your local repository contains the branches that your `origin` remote repository does (assuming you haven't overridden the default behavior by limiting it to specific branches or something). `git help fetch` for more information...

Comment: Thank you, that worked. If you would like to add this as the answer I will accept it. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error message indicates that the reference point from which you are trying to create a new branch does not exist in your local repository (`origin/new_branch_name` in your stated example). The solution to this is to run `git fetch origin` to make sure that those branches that exist your `origin` remote repository have been created locally as well (if you've messed with the default configuration for your `origin` remote, you may need to do `git fetch origin refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` instead).

Additionally, since the argument to `-b` is intended to be the name of the new local branch being created, `git checkout -b master ...` is probably not correct, as you most likely already have a local `master` branch. Most of the time, it makes sense to name the local branch after the remote branch to avoid confusion, so the command you want to run after `git fetch origin` is `git checkout -b new_branch_name origin/new_branch_name`. (You could shorten that to simply `git checkout new_branch_name`, because the default behavior of `git checkout <branch>` if `<branch>` doesn't exist is to look for `origin/<branch>` and to create a local branch with the same name pointed to the remote branch).